# How to get reference to clicked sf::CircleShape?

Tags: c++, sfml, graphic

In my SFML program I am storing drawn CircleShapes in a Vector. How to get reference to one on clicking mouse button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `shape.makeClickable()` function in SFML, all you have to do is:

```
sf::CircleShape* onClick(float mouseX, float mouseY) {//Called each time the players clicks
    for (sf::CircleShape& circle : vec) {
        float distance = hypot((mouseX - circle.getPosition().x), (mouseY - circle.getPosition().y)); //Checks the distance between the mouse and each circle's center
        if (distance <= circle.getRadius())
            return &circle;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

With this vector in your class:

```
std::vector<sf::CircleShape> vec;
```

EDIT
To get ALL circles that you have clicked-on, and not only the first one that it finds :

```
std::vector<sf::CircleShape*> onClick(float mouseX, float mouseY) {//Called each time the players clicks
    std::vector<sf::CircleShape*> clicked;
    for (sf::CircleShape& circle : vec) {
        float distance = hypot((mouseX - circle.getPosition().x), (mouseY - circle.getPosition().y)); //Checks the distance between the mouse and each circle's center
        if (distance <= circle.getRadius())
            clicked.push_back(&circle);
    }
    return clicked;
}
```